# Adding a node to a new parent in javafx

Tags: java, javafx, parent

I'm recently building a javafx program which will work as a school database. I've made a `SceneManager` class which handles all on screen transitions and other gui tasks at runtime. Now i'm intending to add a back button to every visible window so that the user can get back at the previous window anytime. For that I've added the following method to `SceneManager` :

```
public static void addBackButton(Pane from,Pane to){
    Node n1 = to.getChildren().get(0);
    to.getChildren().remove(n1);
    BorderPane fp = new BorderPane();
    fp.setLeft(createBackButton(from));
    fp.setCenter(n1);
    to.getChildren().add(0, fp);
}

public static Button createBackButton(Pane p){
    Button bk = new Button("",new ImageView("icons/appbar.arrow.left2.png"));
    bk.setOnAction((ActionEvent evt)->{
        swapToNext(p);
    });
    return bk;
}
```

However the above is not working. Only the button is being shown without the node 0, which is however generally a heading label in my program. I'm unable to find any general solution to this problem, like the method will be valid for anytype of node in 0. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I removed my old answer, since it wasn't what you were looking for. 
Edit 2: Inspiration in the form of headaches.

[image]

The red color is the pane.

After a nice long weekend, I realized we could just use an anchor pane.

```
    AnchorPane ap = new AnchorPane(p1,back);  //<--- order matters.
    AnchorPane.setBottomAnchor(back, 0.0);    //<--- 0.0 is the distance from that edge
    AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(back, 0.0);
    AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(p1, 0.0);        //<--- we do this to 'bind' the entire pane
    AnchorPane.setBottomAnchor(p1, 0.0);      //<--- to the anchorpane
    AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(p1, 0.0);       //<--- this ensures that it will
    AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(p1, 0.0);         //<--- even show behind the button
```

p1 is the pane, back is the button itself, and the button contains the link 
back to the previous pane.

Here you simply need to return the anchorpane from that addBackButton function. You'll end up with an Anchorpane that contains a button and the previous pane.

I'm going to get more caffeine; I hope I helped. :)

Comment: Thanks. Returning after giving it a try. :)

Comment: Still not working. And note, i was previously also adding the node using `fp.setCenter(n1);` and adding `fp` back to the pane.

Comment: I made a major edit to this answer, so when you get the chance to read it, please let me know if that helped. :)

Comment: Well thanks for the suggestion. But this is, however is not much far different than my approach. I'm just doing kinda same thing in top, and for your wayout, it's in the left. I wanna integrate the button and the topmost node so that the button can't be differentiated from the Pane. And the extra blank area under the button of your Pane can't be used. :(

Comment: One last try, sorry for being so late on the reply. Weekend was pretty long. :)